# Multiple MQs connected to a Java Application deployed on JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, mq, message-driven-bean

I have a Java application deployed on JBoss which is hosted on Openshift. Now for every new MQ(Message Queue) I have to create a new MDB and as number of MQs increases then number of MDBs also increases and my standalone.xml is also getting bigger. More the MQs, more it will be difficult to manage to code. How can I optimize the things here ?

As per my understanding, we can connect only one MQ per MDB. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong and also please help me on possible methods to optimize.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by MQ here ? if it is [message queue](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mq/info) then you can connect several MDBs to single queue. However the messages delivered to queue will consume by MDBs in round robin fashion.

Comment: Yes, by MQ I mean message queue. I don't want to connect several MDBs to a single queue. Rather I wanna do the opposite. I want to connect multiple queues to Single MDB if that is possible. Or I want to find some other alternate solution where in I don't have to create a MDBs for each queue to which my application connects to.